# Provided og:image is not big enough in Facebook linter

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I properly set `og:image` on my website, the facebook linter sees it [(facebook debugger)](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=www.zaerus.com.br) however, it says the image should be at least 200x200, which it is not the case, my image is 250x250 [image](http://d319kw601622ux.cloudfront.net/media/zaerus/img/thumbnail_fb.png).

What could be causing the issue? Could this have anything to do with Cloudfront?

```
Edit: I got around it by switching from this image to another image which is a 
jpg image, but still I couldn't find the cause for the problem since the image
looks fine.
```

Comment: Is the URL you're using a redirect to the actual image? If so, this is a known issue - i believe the debugger and docs will be updated to clarify this issue shortly

Comment: No, I get a HTTP response 200 from the image URL.

Comment: Fix the rest of the warnings too, for example the URL you provided doesn't actually have any OG meta tags: http://pastebin.com/0h5TnJRS

Comment: I've just done this without success, but apparently Facebook doesn't like the image that I'm using since after changing into some other random image it stopped complaining on the linter... What could be wrong with this image? It it bigger than 200x200

Comment: Same problem for my site.  I've even tried converting the image to a different format and back using a different piece of software.  No change.  Other images work fine.  I'm pretty sure Facebook's image parsing is just plain broken.  I filed a bug.  Maybe if/when they fix it, it will fix your problem, too.

Comment: @dgatwood I had a new image generated (a jpg instead of png) and facebook hasn't complained since. Maybe if you try not converting but generating a new one from the original if possible in a different format

Comment: I guess it's still broken. Just tried with a 1500x1500 jpg and it threw that error at me a couple of times, after some hours I tried again and it is now accepted.

Comment: Update: it always throws that error for me on the first time I check an url, resending the form doesn't fix it but hard reloading the page does. The og:image is then used in the post preview too. So does this mean I have to do this for every url of my site? wtf facebook?

Answer (score 27):

This was happening to me.  I was only using the meta og:image tag.  I added the following in the head

```
<link rel="image_src" type="image/jpeg" href="img_path" />
```

and it fixed the problem for me.

Comment: This fixed my problem too, but what's the explanation?

Comment: This is the code that facebook parses out within their code.

Comment: This was driving me mad. Damn you, inaccurate Facebook URL Linter. +1.

Comment: Fixed the linter error for me, but it's still not using the image when I share on Facebook

Comment: did you replace the text 'img_path' in my code with your image?

Answer (score 5):

The thread here is pretty helpful: [og:image Open Graph Warnings image size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15421521/ogimage-open-graph-warnings-image-size)

Generally, FB's parser prefers images that are (1) measured in multiples of 100 and (2) square format.

Comment: And they crop the top and bottom of square images!

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced same error with my custom Web server ServeRick, the solution unexpectedly was to send Content-Length header with images.. without this header facebook didn't accept any of my og:image links

Answer (score 0):

I was having a space in my image path of my image.

Like my image path was http://example.com/**jodha akbar**/image.jpg

If you observe above. The **jodha akbar** directory is having space.

And Facebook was not picking up the path due this special character may be.

I added a PHP str_replace function. And it worked for me.

```
str_replace(" ","%20",$image_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

Converting the same image **from JPG** to **PNG** did the work for me.