# Provided og:image is not big enough

Tags: image, facebook-opengraph, facebook-social-plugins

Since some days I'm experiencing this problem.

Here is my [debug](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://www.swup.it/notizie.php?link=2013/20130312_Monocrome_Demolition_Show)

The image provided is bigger than 200x200 px, it has unique link and there is any redirection on that page.

Linter response is 200.

When I copy and past page's link on fb it give me the choice between 3 images that are smaller than 200x200px and the one I've provided is ignored.

But If I try to share it through "Like button" or "Send button" it works fine.

It sounds like a fb Bug.

Thx

Comment: I know it does not help, but I am experiencing the same problem. [Here is my debug](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.thejoecole.com%2Fgallery%2FPeople%2FAnna_and_Patrick%2FPosed_Pictures-1%2Fphoto-IMG_1129.jpg%23IMG_1129.jpg).

Comment: Hi, there are 2 problems in your debug:


1 You must debug a page with social plugin in it

2 Your image doesn't open : ERROR: Could not open photos/People/Anna_and_Patrick/Posed_Pictures for reading!

Comment: Thank you for checking it out. I was working on the site and messed some things up. The image does open now, and I've actually determined the og:image error was due to a space in the filename of the og:image url.

Comment: I do not get an error anymore, but even though facebook recognizes the og:image and the debugger seems to be ok with it, it doesn't show up on facebook if people comment/like! Weird...

Comment: check tags on your code <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.thejoecole.com/photos/People/Anna_and_Patrick/Posed_Pictures/IMG_1129.jpg">
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg">

Comment: I don't know, man. Debugger [shows nothing wrong](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.thejoecole.com%2Fgallery%2FPlaces%2FGarden_of_the_Gods-1%2Fphoto-IMG_0325.jpg%23IMG_0325.jpg) and the url for the og:image is correct if you [view the source of the page](http://www.thejoecole.com/gallery/Places/Garden_of_the_Gods-1/photo-IMG_0325.jpg#IMG_0325.jpg)...

Comment: Yesterday It said: img url must be provided, right now yes everything is all right.

Comment: Right, I think you viewed it when I was working on it. But, even with the debugger showing everything correct, it doesn't work! Anything shared/liked/commented on doesn't show ANY image at all on Facebook!

Comment: I've discovered that if I paste the link on comments, it works showing the right picture.

Answer (score 3):

I solved using informations from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15346444/provided-ogimage-is-not-big-enough-in-facebook-linter) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15421521/ogimage-open-graph-warnings-image-size) posts.

You can try using an image that is bigger than 200x200, with **dimensions multiple of 100**, and **squared**.

Other useful stuffs are using jpg extension, host the image in the same server of the website and avoid any "strange" chars in filename.

Comment: This worked for me. Also, I read on another answer that 1500 is a good size, so I've kept it at that.

Answer (score 1):

I tried many of the suggestions on this post and others to no avail. The thing finally worked for me (which I have not seen elsewhere) was to add the correct prefix to the  element which I previously was missing entirely.

```
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
```

Not sure if that actually fixed the problem for good or it just jogged the debugger into re-scanning the image (properly) but hopefully it helps someone else.

Comment: FTR, I have this param in the <html> tag,  xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#", and FB is still throwing buggy errors on images that exist, don't redir, are of correct size, type, on the same URL.

Answer (score 0):

I got it done by renaming the image and the og:image url. Give it a try.

Comment: Thx, no way man. I receive same error on every new page on that site. Every page has unique image name and url. ;) It seems to be a bug, Fb opened a case for it.... but after a month nothing has changed.

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with this for a while too. I have tried all shapes and size for the image, renaming it, adding specific og:image:height and :width tags, etc.
The way I 'solved' it is just putting the image I want to show up in the website's root directory and point in og:image to another (1500x1500, btw) image. Facebook linter then tells me that it will use the image in the root directory. And that just works fine ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Even if your image size is not in multiples of 100, it should work if your image is in jpg or jpeg format.
If your image is in png format, no matter what the size is, it will not work. This is based on my tests only. I would like to hear from other devs here.

Answer (score 0):

I use png's all the time. I always use 1920 x 1080 because they look so good on Facebook shares. 85% of the time they  work, sometimes they don't. Sometimes I delete and reload the same photo without renaming or changing a thing and it all of a sudden works. I'm not a real dev so that's all I can offer.

Answer (score 0):

I tried most of these suggestions - double-checked the `<head>` prefix, tried adding the javascript sdk, tried square images, sourcing from different locations, simplifying the file name...

What finally worked was making sure an `<img>` tag for the same image appears in the body! I hid it with CSS / inline style.